# my pc displays GRUB and doesn't starts

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi, bootloader

I just tried to install ubuntu on my PC. I ran Wubi and rebooted computer. My pc has two partitions, one with windows installed and the other with an ubuntu-based linux OS called Linkat, created in my country for education purposes. I tried to run Linkat to see if Ubuntu had replaced the previous OS (linkat). 
Started booting Linkat, and then appeared an error message, and the computer asked me the root password to continue. I have never used this OS, so I don't have the root password, so I decided to use the restoration tool, which was the third option of the bootloader in my computer. I selected to restore only the Linkat partition, because Windows works "well". I left the computer restoring, and I came back later to see how the process went. My computer had the screen black with the word GRUB on it for hours. I turned it off to reboot, and now every time I turn on my computer appears the word GRUB on it, the bootloader doesn't loads and I can't do anything. My pc is a netbook Toshiba NB200. Help please!!

Comment: Have you considered a wipe and reinstall?

Comment: Wubi is not supported anymore as all new Windows 8 systems use gpt partitioning which wubi does not work with.  Windows boots with its own boot loader in MBR, but if you are getting grub, it is because grub is in MBR, but cannot find the rest of grub in the Linux install. Not sure what you reinstalled as that normally is a Windows only install but needs the Windows boot loader. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader